# Do you need to end a story with the same perspective you start with?

Tags: viewpoint

This may seem like an odd question, and perhaps I am over analyzing this a bit too much, as I usually do when it comes to my writing, but here is my concern.

The novel I'm writing is in its last chapter, I know exactly what's going to happen, how it's going to end, etc. but I wrote it in 3rd person omniscient with occasional 3rd person limited for zooming in. **If I started the novel in one character's POV (in 3rd person limited), will the novel feel disconnected if I end it in another character's POV or in omniscient?**

I'm not quite sure if this matters one way or another, but I just thought I'd put the question out there in case anyone could provide an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A story stands or falls on the completion of the story arc. POV is simply about camera angles. You choose the camera angle that best frames the part of the story you are telling at the moment. There is no obligation to end on the same camera angle that you opened with.

There seems to be an obsessive focus on POV in many questions here at the moment. I think it is important to stress that POV is simply a narrative device. It does not determine the shape of the story, nor the reader's sympathy with the protagonist of the story. Nor is there any obligation to tell an entire story from a single POV.

In fact, the only real reason to give a writer any such advice would be if you thought they were not yet a sufficiently skilled writer to manipulate POV successfully, like telling a fledgeling composer not to change time signatures in the middle of a piece. But the point of such advice should only be to suggest that they master the basics before they move on to advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, it's really a matter of how you worked it together. If you're able to make it good while switching between that, then it can make sense that you do that. If you can only stay in on POV because you can't switch without making it confusing, then I wouldn't do that. It's just a matter of what your style is. So if you want to do that and you can pull it off, sure, go for it, you have nothing to lose. It's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of style.  I think of examples of both situations your describe.  There's an audience for both I think.  I might be someone who does not like discontinuity and would go home unsatisfied still looking for some closure while someone else would be entertained and that's it.  I think that if you write something you yourself are satisfied with then you'll be able to 'sell' your novel.